# How to center vertically 2 labels with IB constraint and auto layout iOS

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard, constraints, center

Im am building a user interface using storyboard and autolayout and i'm struggling with layout and constraints, I have a UIView (container) that contains 1 UIView and 2 labels, the UIView has an 16:9 aspect ratio and the two labels are in a UIView with a center vertically constraint witch gives me this in IB : 
[storyboard layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRwzq.png)

for some reasons, probably wrong constraints or missing constraints, layout is different at runtime, (I don't have any auto-layout issues in IB)

[view at runtime not center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8Wcm.png)

So how can I center vertically these 2 labels in my container

I need your help, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The 2 labels should use another view to contain.And make constraint referenced from the green view.The last,you need to make constraint 2 labels to the view you have created just now.The center vertically constraint need refer to the view contains 2 labels

Comment: this is exactly what I have now, the 2 labels are in a view (A) , the view (A) has the center vertically constraint to the superview  (B), but with an aspect ratio on B, it doesn't work, without this constraint now the center vertically constraint is respected